# How to unit test Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Consumer?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I am using spring-cloud-stream to listen to a kinesis stream which is configured is the following way

using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        binder:
          auto-create-stream: false
      bindings:
        processOrder-in-0:
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
    function:
      definition: processOrder;

cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: us-east-1
```

I have a @Bean declared as processOrder which is able to receive the events from the kinesis stream.

```
@Service
public class EventConsumer{

@Bean
public Consumer<Event> processOrder(){
    return this::processEvent;
}

private void processEvent(final Event event){
      //perform operations
}
```

I would like to know how to write a JUnit test for this funcitonality, how can I possibily send mock kinesis events to test the processOrder,processEvent functions ?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest approach would be to create a new Bean which contains

```
public void processEvent(final Event event){
  //perform operations
}
```

You could then simply Mock "EventConsumer" with a normal MockitioMock and test your logic. Saving you the trouble of having to start the spring context every time your tests runs.

Comment: I understand what you mean to say, this can be a possibility. Just in case I want to keep the method private can you suggest how to trigger the function via @Bean context?